# "Erase tool" in texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

So I've got a picture where I texture painted with white (look pic #1 here)

[image]

My question is: how do I delete or erase what I've just painted? Because if I click "ctrl" it just paints black. (look picture #2)

[image]

Is there really no other way to fix this except just deleting the picture and adding another one?
I tried "Erase Alpha" in the settings of the brush but it just makes it transparent.
So, what if I have a complex painting where I just made a simple little mistake, do I need to delete the whole thing and add a new picture to start from scratch?
Is there no "erase tool" in blender for texture paint?

Comment: As you have found out, there is an erase tool. You would want to use layers, but Blender doesn't have image layers.

Comment: If you've only just made the mistake you can use Ctrl-Z to undo the last actions but that depends on the number of undo steps you have set under Edit > Preferences > System > Memory & Limits.

Comment: If you were to Erase in say Photoshop, that would also be a destructive edit because of not having replacement pixels for under your brush marks. Your best bet is to paint through a camera view to a new iteration of the image using a second image texture with 0 alpha as if using a transparency layer in Gimp or PS. Or, maybe look into marking with Grease Pencil instead of painting into the image directly.